# Error method not implemented

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get the start coordinates and the size of the element in a android app using uiautomator and selenium. I was stuck at this point. The code says that the WebElement is a interface. So I even tried to typecast it but it was saying that was redundant type cast as the return type was RemoteWebElement and it also had an implementation. This is my code and the following error occurs. Can someone please help me out??

```
130    WebElement webElement = LIST_ELEMENTS_XPATH.findElement(this.elementOperator.getDriver());
131            Rectangle rectangle = webElement.getRect();
132            int listX = rectangle.getX();
133            int listY = rectangle.getY();
134            int listHeight = rectangle.getHeight();
135            int listWidth = rectangle.getWidth();
```

And this is the error

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Method has not yet been implemented (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 18 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:32:46'
System info: host: '38c9860577c9', ip: '10.55.22.63', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.4', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities [{appPackage=com.amazon.dee.app, deviceScreenSize=1080x1920, networkConnectionEnabled=true, recreateChromeDriverSessions=true, noReset=true, warnings={}, databaseEnabled=false, deviceName=WUJ01NML4S, platform=LINUX, deviceUDID=WUJ01NML4S, appActivity=.Launcher, desired={appActivity=.Launcher, appPackage=com.amazon.dee.app, recreateChromeDriverSessions=true, noReset=true, newCommandTimeout=300, platformName=Android, udid=WUJ01NML4S, deviceName=Android Device}, newCommandTimeout=300, platformVersion=6.0, webStorageEnabled=false, locationContextEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, deviceModel=F3216, platformName=Android, udid=WUJ01NML4S, deviceManufacturer=Sony}]
Session ID: 4c06d952-bc1b-4afd-9a0c-eb47098dbb4e

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:40)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:327)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileElement.execute(DefaultGenericMobileElement.java:33)
    at io.appium.java_client.MobileElement.execute(MobileElement.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement.execute(AndroidElement.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.getRect(RemoteWebElement.java:400)
    at com.amazon.alexa.comms.testsdk.mobile.alexaapp.pages.comms.conversationthread.ConversationThreadPageAndroid.scrollUp(ConversationThreadPageAndroid.java:131)
```

Comment: I believe it states that getRect() is not a method for webElement object

Comment: yeah because WebElement is a interface. So I even tried to typecast it to the class(RemoteWebElement) where the implementation is present and then it says redundant typeCast.